# Help with son's 18 V car

Tags: relay, wiring, 12v, diagram, troubleshooting

I need help with the wiring on my son's car.
I'm trying to run 2 x front and 2 x rear #QG550 12 V 45rmp motors using independent 18 V power supplies, 18 V front and 18 V rear.
I wish to keep the forward/stop/reverse 6-pin switch and the hi/lo speed 6- pin switch.

I had a wiring diagram drawn up for me but I thought the foot pedel was only a 3-pin switch. I have now learned it is a momentary 6-pin switch(16A 125/250vac)T125.
How do i wire 
[image: 3rd time luckey]

I have also a 5-pin relay and two 8-pin DPDT relays to run my second system.

Can some one look over my diagram and help me please. Sorry if my first post was brief - I was hoping to upload it. Also the bottom right DPDT relay doesn't look wired right too.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kid car 4x4 3-6 pin foot switch](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/216912/kid-car-4x4-3-6-pin-foot-switch)

Comment: I removed the original post,

Comment: @DylanAssetta: This question is as bad as the original and will suffer the same fate. You haven't posted any of the information requested in that question. You've got one down-vote already so you need to move quickly. Show the wiring diagram. Show the switch. Show the links to the switch datasheet ...

Comment: Sorry just downloaded the app, hope the diagram helps

Comment: You really think we can read that diagram!?  I didn't even bother reading the rest of the post, just -1, closing, and moving on.

Comment: The schematic is low resolution and barely readable but we may be able to figure something out from it. (1)What is the motor rating (volts and amps) and (2) what is the switch rating (amps)? (3) Why are you using relays? Do you think the switches aren't capable on their own? (4) What are the relay specifications / part numbers. Put the additional information **in your original post** and not in the comments.

Comment: @DylanAssetta the picture is too small, that's the problem. Upload a high resolution copy.

Comment: Clearer pic any more info needed?

Comment: And i am using relays to power them separate for more run time

Comment: The second version of the schematic is the same low resolution as the original. Also, please use the spell check and capitalise and punctuate properly to make it easier to read. I've fixed it up twice but I'll tire of it.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, ill try again if still bad ill get my partners phone,

Comment: Latest photo smaller than previous two. I give up.

Comment: That last photo was what i was sent idk whats happening even my screen shot it uploading blurry :S

Comment: @DylanAssetta im assuming they texted you the pictures? SMS/MMS pictures tend to get scaled/compressed down automatically by most phones. They should email you the original if they still have it.

Comment: I marked it as answered, i only need the hook up pins 2+in 4-in 3+out 6-our (only example) and i cant read ladder :(  and one 18v supply only gives 20 minute run time. Its ok ill crack out the testlight n multimeter thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagram you created is what is known as a field wiring diagram.  This type of diagram is only useful in showing how components are connected within a system.  Beyond a wiring reference, diagrams such as this are usually almost useless in demonstrating logic or as a troubleshooting tool.

The language that this is frequently converted to is a schematic ladder diagram.  This isn't to say that there aren't other methods of stepping through the logic of your system -such as flow charts - but ladder diagrams are usually the most spoken language to convert from a logical flow to real world wiring.

Ladder diagrams allow you divide and conquer in drawing and stepping through the functions you are trying to accomplish.  Everything in Ladder Diagrams flow from Left to Right and steps down.

A quick google search of ladder diagrams resulted in this link which may be helpful in demonstrating what I am referring to: http://www.seattlerobotics.org/encoder/may97/ladder5.jpg

If I were you I would also consider Paralleling each group of 3 6V batteries to make a single 18V source rather than 2 sources.  This would allow some simplification from the start.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5kewg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>